# Start PowerPoint viewer in full screen (kiosk) mode

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, windows-xp-embedded

I have Magic Info Pro (samsung) Software, and I installed on a remote screen PowerPoint Viewer.

Every time it starts it displays the title bar.  My boss does not want this bar displayed.

I see that it is possible to right click while PPT is running and go to FullScreen Mode.

I also found that it is possible to execute PPT like.

```
C:/PowerPoint Viewer/ /F C:/welcome.ppt
```

And this would do exactly what we wish.

But MagicInfo is executing this Presentations, and I can't change the code of this software.

Is there a way to let PowerPoint start in Windows with specific parameters like /F? It is OK if it would start every time with that parameter since this computer is really just a node where content is saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and I'm using Window 7 Embedded and Powerpoint Viewer 2010.
If you are using Powerpoint Viewer 2010, you will have to install Office 2010 SP1 otherwise the presentation won't loop.

Add the switch `/f` to the registry keys

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPointViewer.Show.11\Shell\Show\Command 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPointViewer.Show.12\Shell\Show\Command
```

It's probably not needed to edit both keys but I'm not sure which one is used.

The Default parameter for the registry keys should look something like

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\pptview.exe /f "%1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the /f flag to the following keys to get PowerPoint Viewer to open in full screen.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPointViewer.SlideShow.11\shell\Show\command
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPointViewer.SlideShow.12\shell\Show\command
```

The suggestions in the accepted answer didn't work for me.

Comment: This solution differs from the [actually accepted one](http://superuser.com/a/615873/257269) because the keys are `... .SlideShow. ...` instead of `... .Show. ...`.

Answer (score 1):

FYI it looks like these registry settings re-set themselves (maybe after updates?).  Here are the contents of a regfile to easily re-apply:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPointViewer.Show.11\shell\Show\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\pptview.exe /f \"%1\""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPointViewer.Show.12\shell\Show\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\pptview.exe /f \"%1\""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPointViewer.SlideShow.11\shell\Show\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\pptview.exe /f \"%1\""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPointViewer.SlideShow.12\shell\Show\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\pptview.exe /f \"%1\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft PPT has the ability to save your powerpoint as a Windows Media Video (WMV) which can be initiated on startup in full screen mode and looping. It maybe a bit resource intensive but it's a quick fix